# Promise function not returning results

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm using `instagram-scraping` module to display all posts with a specific hash tag but I get an issue using a function to return finded items.

```
// in my middleware
function getInstagramPostsByHashTag(hashtag) {
  return ig.scrapeTag(hashtag).then(result => {
    console.log(result); // all posts are displayed in my console
    return result;
  });
}

// in my ejs template i send the function getInstagramPostsByHashTag()
<%=getInstagramPostsByHashTag("instagram")%> // nothing is displayed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return the posts from the function because the function has already returned at this point. That's because `.then()` is asynchronous. It executes the provided callback when the work (fetching the posts) is done, but the function continues to run after the call to `.then()`, and because you return nothing, you get nothing.

If you want a function to return the result of an asynchronous operation, you have to return a promise from the function itself. To help developers with that, there's the `async function` that automatically returns a promise. In an async function, you can wait for other promises with the `await` keyword. Your function would look like this as an async function:

```js
async function getInstagramPostsByHashTag(hashtag) {
  return await ig.scrapeTag(hashtag)
}
```

But this is redundant because it returns exactly the same as a direct call to `ig.scrapeTag(hashtag)` would do. I don't really know ejs but I think the best thing you could do is something like this (only pseudocode, again, I don't know how rendering with ejs works):

```
posts = insta.scrapeTag("blablabla")
    then
        ejs.render("<%=posts%>", {posts})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I now have enought advises.